# Reading file with different formats

Tags: file-format, file-opening

I am a new user to Linux. I have several files and documents in my directory and sometimes when I want to read or display data in these files, I do not know which command I need to type for this purpose. I would be appreciated if one helps me with that.

Comment: Given a file named `foo`, type `file foo`. It will tell you what type of file it is, which should give you a clue as to what program to read it with.

Comment: I tried to use this command with different files with different end forma,i.e docx, xlsx and pdf but each time I get this massage (No such file or directory) although these files are actually found.

Comment: In that case, you have a bigger problem than identifying "which command" goes with which file type. See [Files listed by bash but unaccessible (or inaccessible)](http://superuser.com/q/799720/354511).

Comment: You mean desktop environment, not console, right? Please specify that, beacause most answers focus on console.

Comment: @Kamil My answer covers both text terminals and graphic/desktop (X) applications.

Comment: I didn't meant your answer vinc17. There are some suggestions in comments that apply only to console.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to display text in the terminal, with automatic conversion to text, you can use `less <file>` with [Wolfgang Friebel's lesspipe](https://www.zeuthen.desy.de/~friebel/unix/lesspipe.html), which will detect some file types and do the conversion transparently.

For graphic applications, you can use `xdg-open <file>`, which will automatically select the "right" application.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few commands you can type to view contents of files. There are:

- `vim` or `vi` which is good for viewing text files and creating shell
  scripts
- `less` or `more` which is good for viewing log files ( I find `less` more useful in that case). You cannot change anything with `less` or `more` but is good for viewing.
- `gedit` which is a `GUI` tool that will show text/log/conf files.
- `cat` can show contents of a file but your better off using `less`

Comment: Thanks for you all. I tried all your suggestions but each time I get either errors (-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline') or (Missing name or redirect).

Comment: What exactly are you typing in?

Comment: As I indicated previously, I am trying to view of read the content of some files on Xterm for Linux desktop. For example a file with pdf or psk format.

Comment: Do you have a pdf viewer installed? Can you type: man -k pdf